# Play! framework 2.1 - scheduling async tasks (Java)

Tags: java, akka, playframework-2.1

I've just updated Play! framework to version 2.1 and scala to version 2.10...

Now my Play! app is broken. It seems that the Akka API has changed. I can't find the Akka's version used now but I think it's the last version...

I just read the migration guide : http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/project/migration-guide-2.0.x-2.1.x.html.

I've updated my code accordingly:

```
Akka.system().scheduler().scheduleOnce(
    new FiniteDuration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS), 
    new MyRunnableJob(), 
    Akka.system().dispatcher());
```

But an error occurs as follows :

error: no suitable method found for `scheduleOnce(akka.util.FiniteDuration,Runnable,ExecutionContext)`

Yet we find it on the API documentation :

http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.1.1/index.html#akka.actor.Scheduler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Akka version should be 2.1.x, and you should try to send in a `scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration`.

It seems like you have some old akka jars on the path, since the `akka.util.FiniteDuration` doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer resolve my problem. By the way, I've run the play clean command so I don't understand why old version is still present.

I've seen that I have these libs present inside my play! folder :
./repository/local/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.10
./repository/local/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor/2.0.1

No idea why...